# couchDB-Python storing Date Value

Tags: python, database, couchdb

I was following the CouchDb tutorial from http://packages.python.org/CouchDB/mapping.html. This seems to be outdated since the modules dont work as per the program. So I just re wrote the CouchDB python script to store few values and here is my script. But when I lookup the CouchDb database I can find the name and age but the **date value is not stored**. Can someone tell me how to go about doing this? Also is there an updated python CouchDB tutorial?

```
from couchdb import Server, Document
from couchdb.mapping import TextField, IntegerField, DateTimeField 
import datetime

class Person(Document):
    name  = TextField()
    age = IntegerField()
    added = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server('http://localhost:5984')
    try:
        db = server.create('person')
    except Exception:
        db = server['person']

    person = Person(name='John Doe', age=42)
    db.save(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Couchdb example refers to a default value of `datetime.now` but you are using `datetime.datetime.now()`. The extra `datetime` is not an issue but you might want to consider using `from datetime import datetime` for readability.

The issue is that you are calling a function and returning its value, while the example passes a function object which the Couchdb can call anytime it needs a default value.

Get rid of the two parentheses and you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. How ever the couchdb does not show the data even when I removed the parentheses.

Comment: Did you create new records? The `default` is only going to have an effect when you create a new Couchdb record.

Comment: The db.save(person) creates a new record, I see name and age in the new record since I am passing those arguments.

Comment: The problem is not related to readability, nor to object type. There are 2 different `Document` class!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and after glancing the code, I noticed there are 2 `Document` class! If you are gonna use field mapping, use `couchdb.mapping.Document` instead.